# How to Install a Techno Flange

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I recently had some plumbing work done on my house but still need to install a toilet after I finish tiling the floor.

We were left with the following flange and a toilet drain pipe sticking about 3 inches above the floor. http://www.ipscorp.com/plumbing/watertite/closetflanges/technoflange

How do you install this type of flange? The drain pipe fits inside the flange, is that the way it should be?

Also, the flange should ideally sit on top of the tile, correct?

Anything else I should know? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is made to glue to 3" or 4" drain pipe. I can't tell for sure but it looks like it glues over 3" or into 4".

You need to make sure the flange and glue are compatible with your pipe. If the pipe is white it is probably PVC, make sure you have the PVC flange and glue. If your pipe is black it is ABS, make sure you have...blah, blah, blah.

The flange may be set to rest on top of the finished floor or flush with the finished floor. It needs to be secured to the floor as well (note the screw holes). It might be easiest to glue it on and fasten it to the sub-floor with stainless screws, then tile up to it. The tile won't need to be perfect because the toilet should hide the immediate area.